# Bounty Still Missing

Tags: support, bounty

Re. question: [Incorrectly Deleted User - user31385](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/incorrectly-deleted-user-user31385). The issue I raised in the question has been resolved, apart from a 400 point bounty that has still not been restored to my account.

In the comments on the answer I was told this by animuson:

> It needs a developer to fix. Essentially, when a profile
>   is deleted, any bounties awarded to them are changed so that
>   TargetUserId = null, but reassociating posts manually does not change
>   that TargetUserId back to the user. It just leaves it null, so the
>   system doesn't think it belongs to you despite it being on your post.

*How can I contact a developer in order to restore this bounty to me?*

Comment: Probably your best bet is to use the "contact us" link (in the page footer).  That'll get it into SE's ticketing system.

Comment: Thanks, @Monica.